# Exception while making search query to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am using elastic search 5.3 and for that, I used jest client 2.0.4.

I have the use case to provide soft timeout while executing search query I provide that in

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource().from(10).size(100).timeout(100).build;
```

But I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Error while executing the query: {"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception",      "reason":"failed to parse setting [timeout] with value [600] as a time value: unit is missing or                  unrecognized"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse setting [timeout] with value [600] as a time   value: unit is missing or unrecognized"}]
```

Comment: Please format your code and error

Comment: @Arount it actually seems to be there.

Comment: It looks like the first Bing (ugh) result for the error answers the question: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-are-supported-date-unit-in-decay-function/96199 you seem to need a character indicating the unit of time, I'd try an 's' or maybe use '10m'

Comment: @Joshua Drake I tried to both by providing unit still it didnt worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Solved issue by providing unit of time.